# How to do soft Image Edges with background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I generated dynamic color from images and make it background color.
I want soft edges of background image and color. How do I implement it?

[image: Ugly Images]

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 0.5,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(child: ProductImageWidget()),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: ProductNameWidget(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    child: Image.network(
        "src",
        height: 150.0,
        width: 100.0,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your **ProductImageWidget()** with ClipRReact. Where there is a property called borderRadius.

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    child: ProductImageWidget(),
)
```

Or you can use this widget in the inner code of **ProductImageWidget()** as a parent widget

Comment: I don't want corner radius. I want blur image edges for smooth color transition to background color. Thanks!

Comment: can you show an example? thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a **ClipRRect** and a **BackDropFilter** to get the effect that you want. By the way this effect is called **frosted glass**, you can find many info about it. Let me show you an example (*I not tested it :)* ).

```
ClipRRect(
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
    child:  Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    border: Border.all(
      width: 0.5,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(24),
    ),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(child: ProductImageWidget()),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: ProductNameWidget(),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

),
),